# Postman : where cookies are saved?

Tags: api, cookies, postman

I have 2 opened tab in Postman. One tab calls login API, second calls protected page. If I call the second tab without calling the first I get "Bad request":

[image]

but I call the first before with valid credentials:

[image]

and the call the second again, then I get protected page:

[image]

Where is it and how to get it to set inside my application?

Comment: Postman uses browser as a client to call hence it stores cookies and by default browser sends all cookies it has associated with a domain. If you want to get cookies outside of Postman it has a Code link to generate a code to make a call with cookies for example for Curl.

Comment: @webdizz, really, I want to know, which cookies are returned and get it

Comment: You can view cookies from Cookies tab in Postman

Comment: "how to get it to set inside my application" -- what application are you talking about here? Are you looking for a way to manipulate Postman's cookies from a "test" script that will execute within Postman? Or does "my application" mean some other application that you're developing and you want it to have similar behavior as Postman regarding cookies? In the latter case, please update the question to tell us more about that application, what language you're coding in, which libraries you're using, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Postman uses a javascript engine [based on node js](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/intro_to_scripts/), so cookies are saved in the regular way nodejs does.

About how to use the cookies inside postman, you can use them like this:

```
console.log(postman.getResponseCookie('cookie name').value);
```

[Here](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/11/28/using-the-interceptor-to-read-and-write-cookies/) you can find an example of how to manipulate cookies using postman.

If you only want to inspect the cookies you can use the [cookie manager](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies/).

Answer (score 1):

Cookies saved by postman can be viewed by clicking cookies button under Send button.

[Refer this](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/cookies/)